# Automatically run a powershell script elevated

Tags: powershell, uac

Is there a way to run a powershell script automatically in Elevated mode?

I am trying to automate some post-image tasks without user intervention, but am getting caught with the UAC. Is there a way to "bypass" this, possibly by running as another user?

I want the machine to reboot and run various scripts, so it can complete the build process with no intervention.

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 2):

Startup scripts run with elevated privileges. Can you add your script to the Startup scripts in `Computer Configuration`/`Windows Settings`/`Scripts (startup/Shutdown)`?

I'm sure there are other ways to pass credentials but this has worked for me in the past

Comment: Is there a way to programatically add a script to the local startup scripts folder? Say I have 3 scripts to run - coul I add a line in script A to copy  script B to the startup script folder and delete script A and then add a line in Script B to copy script C to the scripts folder and delete Script B?

Comment: can you expand on this? Have added it in there, but it doesn't want to play. :-(

Comment: Are there any errors in the event log?  Where is the file loacated?

Comment: File is located in c:\windows\system32\grouppolicy\machine\scripts\startup (computer is back at the office so will check the log tomorrow) - Thanks, Dave. Ben

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of [a self elevating PowerShell script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script.aspx).